# How to solve this array?

Tags: php, arrays

Given an array with number of power units consumed by different home appliances over the weekdays. You have to find the total consumption of each appliance in the array. The result array should be like ('REFRIGERATOR'=>47,'WASHINGMACHINE'=>29, ...)

```
$consumption = array(
    'MONDAY' => array(
        'REFRIGERATOR' => array(3, 9, 7), 
        'WASHINGMACHINE' => array(2, 4, 2, 8)), 
    'TUESDAY' => array(
        'REFRIGERATOR' => array(5, 3, 8), 
        'OVEN' => array(4, 1, 4)), 
    'WEDNESDAY' => array(
        'TV' => array(6, 9), 
        'REFRIGERATOR' => array(2, 3, 5, 2)), 
    'THURSDAY' => array(
        'TV' => array(5, 3, 3, 2), 
        'FAN' => array(4, 9, 8, 5)), 
    'FRIDAY' => array(
        'WASHINGMACHINE' => array(8, 5), 
        'OVEN' => array(3, 9, 7))
    );
```

Output: Array ( [REFRIGERATOR] => 47 [WASHINGMACHINE] => 29 [OVEN] => 28 [TV] => 28 [FAN] => 26 )

Comment: 1) We're not here to do your homework for you 2) Provide the code you've tried, with an explanation of what isn't working, with any error messages you're getting in full.

Comment: please help bro..

Comment: Bro? If you've not even attempted it, then we have nothing to help with.

Comment: foreach ($consumption as $k=>$subArray) {
  foreach ($subArray as $id=>$value) {
    $consumption[$id]+=$value;
  }
}

print_r($consumption);

Comment: Please edit your question with the code, putting it in comments makes it hard to read.

Comment: Please, read these links to have in mind how to write your next questions: [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) | [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) | [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). After the comments it seems complete now.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your code is mostly correct, and just needs a couple of tweaks:

```
$consumption = array( 'MONDAY' => array('REFRIGERATOR' => array(3, 9, 7), 'WASHINGMACHINE' => array(2, 4, 2, 8)), 'TUESDAY' => array('REFRIGERATOR' => array(5, 3, 8), 'OVEN' => array(4, 1, 4)), 'WEDNESDAY' => array('TV' => array(6, 9), 'REFRIGERATOR' => array(2, 3, 5, 2)), 'THURSDAY' => array('TV' => array(5, 3, 3, 2), 'FAN' => array(4, 9, 8, 5)), 'FRIDAY' => array('WASHINGMACHINE' => array(8, 5), 'OVEN' => array(3, 9, 7)) );

$data = array();

foreach ($consumption as $k=>$subArray) {
    foreach ($subArray as $id=>$value) {
        if(!isset($data[$id])) {
            $data[$id] = 0;
        }
        $data[$id]+=array_sum($value);
    }
}
```

Note the following:

1) Don't override variables you're using. I've created a new `$data` array which stores the data you're wanting.

2) $value is actually the array of consumption values. Use array_sum to get the total sum of that array, then add it to the relevant tally.

3) Make sure to create the index in advance of adding to it so you don't get errors.